# get separate access token for a particular user in wso2 IS

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created Service Provider and wso2 IS successfully integrated with LDAP, tested API and able to generate access token for user.

The wso2 IS generates same access token every time for a single user, even if i hit /oauth2/token api multiple times, Is it possible in wso2 IS to

1. generate separate access token for same user everytime i call /oauth2/token
2. wso2 IS able to handle this type of token management

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 IS generates a unique access token for the combination of
  1. OAuth2.0 client ID (client/application)
  2. Authorized user (resource owner)
  3. Approved scopes (for the unique set)

If a valid access token already exists for the above combination in ACTIVE state that token will be returned. If you need a new token one of the above parameters MUST change.

A new feature JIRA has already been captured with regard to this:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4404